# Java HashMap performing put() and get() in same line

Tags: java, hashmap

I am using a HashMap<String, Integer> to keep track of count of an occurrence of a specific string. I am performing this operation in a single-thread manner in the following way:

```
   HashMap<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
   // List<String≥ words = ...;
   for (String word : words) {
      if (!count.containsKey(word)) {
          count.put(word, 0);
      }
      count.put(word, count.get(word) + 1);
   }
```

Is it possible, for the same word, the count increases by more than 1 because I am performing a put and get on the same key at the same time? i.e. Let's say the word = "hello". Initially, count.get(word) => 1. When I perform count.put(word, count.get(word) + 1), if I do count.get(word), instead of getting 2, I get 3.

Comment: `count.add(word, 0);` should not even compile...

Comment: Aside from your question, above code can be rewritten into something more readable (for people familiar with streams added in Java 8) into `Map<String, Long> count  = words.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()));`

Comment: My question is not about using streams. I made up this scenario to ask specifically for behavior of put() and get() in the same line of HashMap

Comment: btw, no it's not a possible explanation, please post the content of `words `

Comment: That is why I said "Aside from your question" :) Anyway "*I am performing a `put` and `get` on the same key at the same time?*" in single-thread environment those instructions will not be invoked "at the same time" but sequentially, specifically `count.put(word, count.get(word) + 1);` `put` method *arguments* will need to be evaluated (so `count.get(word)+1` will generate result first) and then `count.put(...);` can be invoked. "if I do count.get(word), instead of getting 2, I get 3." not with assumptions from this question (single thread and printing value fro correct map using correct key).

Answer (score 2):

`Map` has methods `compute` and `merge` that would allow to implement shorter updates of the values for the keys:

1. [`compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

```java
for (String word : words) {
    count.compute(word, (w, prev) -> prev == null ? 1 : prev + 1);
}
```

2. [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

```java
for (String word : words) {
    count.merge(word, 1, (prev, one) -> prev + one);
}
```

Lambda expression `(prev, one) -> prev + one` is actually a function of two `int` arguments returning their sum, therefore it may be replaced with a method reference [`Integer::sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#sum-int-int-):

```java
for (String word : words) {
    count.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions directly: no it is not possible for the statement `count.put(word, count.get(word) + 1)` to increment the value by more than 1. Although the two method calls are in the same statement they are performed sequentially: the `get` is performed first to find the second argument to pass to the `put`.

You can combine your missing key test and initialisation into a single statement:

```
count.putIfAbsent(word, 0);
```

This conveniently returns the value afterwards, allowing:

```
count.put(word, 1 + count.putIfAbsent(word, 0));
```

However there is also a method that already combines those two operations:

```
count.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely safe to do it in a single thread.
No, it's not possible that "count increases by more than 1 because I am performing a put and get on the same key at the same time" because two operations never can happen at the same time with single-threaded execution.

Code `count.put(word, count.get(word) + 1);` will execute commands in following order:

```
Integer value1 = count.get(word);
int value2 = value1.intValue();
int value3 = value2 + 1;
Integer value4 = new Integer(value3);
count.put(word, value4);
```

By the way, your code will produce quite a lot of garbage and will be not very effective.

This way is more effective:

```
private static class CounterHolder{
    int value;
}

Map<String, CounterHolder> count = new HashMap<>();
List<String> words = ...
for (String word : words) {
    CounterHolder holder;
    if (count.containsKey(word)) {
        holder = new CounterHolder();
    } else {
        holder = new CounterHolder();
        count.put(word, holder);
    }
    ++holder.value;
}
```